# Network based on Netgear FVS318 extremely slow

Tags: slow-connection, netgear

A network I maintain uses an FVS318 as a router, with a separate switch. Communication within the network is slow. Out to the internet is even slower.

As it stands there is one patch from the FVS to the switch and no other devices directly connected to the FVS because any that are run so slowly they might as well not be connected to the network.

Swapping in a bog-standard home router dramatically increases network speed, but that's not a viable solution because some of the enterprise features of the FVS are required.

There are quite a few complaints about this on the Netgear forum, but Netgear support have not been forthcoming with any help - so I turn to you all: any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the config?  On Cisco equipment, you can just type "show run" to see the config.  I've used some NetGear equipment for 11 years now.  Nothing is popping to mind, but maybe it would if I had some more data.

Comment: Not on-site and remote administration is a bit sketchy for some reason. I'll most likely be on site on Monday, so I'll see what I can do then. Thanks very much for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Was the internal network performance evaluated too when testing with the "bog-standard home router?" If so, was it also better?

If the internal network performance stayed the same - slow, then you might consider the traffic flowing through the network itself and possibly consider isolating the systems for additional testing.

Comment: Traffic was much faster with the "bog-standard home router" (a cheapass Dynamode, I think). To the extent that one user went from complaining that Sage over the network was "unusable" to insisting it was as responsive as a copy with all the data locally stored.

Comment: How long was the test? And did the network performance revert back immediately when reverting back from the test?

Comment: The test was over two days. Network performance immediately became worse upon reverting. I should have more details on Monday! Thanks for your interest.

Comment: The Netgear should normally not have any impact on the local traffic occurring across the additional switch. This is probably a hint that the actual root cause is not limited to just the Netgear - maybe its a contributing factor, but there is maybe something else going on too.

Comment: Probably need to upgrade to an FVS-338 if you have to stay with Netgear. The FVS-318 is a small potatoes device that most bog-standard home routers can kick to the curb. I know, I used to run them and that was the upgrade path back in 2009. Moved to Cisco ASA-5505 soon after and never looked back.